# issue on lvds with 3.14{YOCTO}

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree

I am using a linux **3.14 kernel** for kontron smarc-samx6i. Now the current issue is My **LVDS** display shows a image from **bootloader** but after my **yocto kernel is up** nothing is showing on my display. only a **black screen backlight**. Please point me what goes wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I just recovered the issue the problem is beacause of the bootarg that I provided on uboot i just give both video parameter for lvds and hdmi. Now its working :-)